# JPA 2.0 hobernate 4+ @OneToMany unidirectional set

Tags: jpa, insert-update, one-to-many, hibernate-4.x

I read a lot of topic and forum about @OneToMany but unfortunatelly any of this couldn't help.

For example we have Entities like these:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MANAGER")
public class Manager{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "MAN_ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAN_ID", updatable=true)     
    private Set<Workers> workers;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAN_ID", updatable=true)   
    private Set<Helpers> helpers;

...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKERS")
public class Workers{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "HELPERS")
public class Helpers{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

...
}
```

And now im trying to save first time Manager object (with not empty both sets)

```
Session session = getSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(holder);
tx.commit();
```

In return i see how hibernate tries to do inserts, but there is not update for workers and helpers.
When im getting Manager back from DB, both lists are empty (null).
What am i missing here?

Comment: Do you have the getters and setters as public/protected?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like i was missing nullable

```
@JoinColumn(name = "MAN_ID", nullable = false)
```